# Update value in controller using resource in AngularJS runtime

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My controller code

```
//first $http request to get results.wesites
// i want to get $scope.totalchatsdone as an integer dont know how 
$scope.totalchatsdone  = function (){  
    var i =0;
    $.each(results.websites,function(index,website){
    var id = website.id;
    $scope.tech = techRepository.getTech.query({ id }, function(data) {
        console.log("total--"+ data.total)
        i += data.total;
    });
});
console.log("i is--"+i)
return i;
};
```

my factory code

```
factory('techRepository', ['$resource', function ($resource,$http) {
    return {
        getTech: $resource(base_url+'/testapi/chats/:id', {id: '@id'}, {query: {method: 'GET'}})
    };
}])
```

> What i want :-
>
> I want to get $scope.totalchatsdone as an integer

Edit :-  console pic-- i dont know why i is 0 here,see in console please(why it is not taking total value ?? )... 
[image]

Comment: and what do you get right now ?

Comment: @Guti `console.log($scope.totalchatsdone)` gives me same function

Comment: You define as function know, so you call it as "$scope.totalchatsdone()" and let me know

Comment: Maths already wrote what i wanted to write :)

Comment: @MathsRkBala call to where  ??

Comment: @MathsRkBala @Guti In controller it is `0` and in view it is blank

Comment: @PraveenKumar I dont know your code and where you want the integer. So please provide the view part variable. You get 0 so please test console.log(results.websites);

Comment: @MathsRkBala as written in function its working fine if i console log i its giving me exact result what i want...

Comment: "i" gets consonle.logged before you get data.total cuz that one is asynchronous

Comment: @Guti How to make it synchronous then ??

Answer (score 1):

**`query()`** behaves as a promise, i.e before your execution of each loop is completed. Your **variable `i`** get consoled.

Comment: instead of variable x you can use it with $scope in case you want to attach it to view.

Comment: Its still 0 in controller :)

Comment: Just initialize 'i', dont assign any value to it;